# Implementing CUDA kernel to use row wise features for histogram

Tags: cuda, numba

I am trying to write a Cuda kernel to generate row-wise histogram based on the input feature set (2 x 6) where each feature row (each having 6 features) is to generate a histogram having nbins=10.
I have implemented the below code but it doesn’t seem to generate the correct row-wise histogram.

```
import numba
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

np.random.seed(0)
feature = np.random.randint(1, high=6, size=(2,6), dtype=int)
output = np.zeros(20).astype(np.float32).reshape(2,10)

### Kernal Configuration
threads_per_block = 6
blocks = 2

# moving data to device
d_feature = cuda.to_device(feature)
d_output = cuda.to_device(output)
feature_size = d_feature.shape[1]


@cuda.jit
def row_wise_histogram(feature, output, n):
    xmin = np.float32(-4.0)
    xmax = np.float32(4.0)
    idx = cuda.grid(1)
    nbins = 10
    bin_width = (xmax - xmin) / nbins
    for i in range(n):
        # Each thread will take all the row features to generate historgram
        input = feature[idx][i]
        bin_number = np.int32(nbins * (np.float32(input) - np.float32(xmin)) / (np.float32(xmax) - np.float32(xmin)))
        if bin_number >= 0 and bin_number < output.shape[1]:
            cuda.atomic.add(output[idx], bin_number, 1)


row_wise_histogram[blocks, threads_per_block](d_feature, d_output, feature_size)

print(d_output.copy_to_host())
```

And the out results in

```
[[ 0.  0.   0.   0.   0.  0.  81111.  81111.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.   0.   0.   0. 162222.  0.  81111. 0.]]
```

which is wrong, Will appreciate it if I can get help with the issue inside the row_wise_historgram function!

Comment: You only have 2 rows in your features, right?  And your kernel strategy is one thread per row, right?  So why are you launching 2 blocks of 6 threads each = 12 threads total?  You only need 2 threads for this.  Your bins range from -4 to 4, right?  So why are you trying to histogram values up to 6?

Comment: @RobertCrovella, you are right about the 2 rows feature. Regarding the kernel strategy, I was thinking to use threads equal to feature size to transfer them to shared memory(sm) and then using the sm for a histogram. In the future, I will be using feature size multiple of wrap, hence it will come in handy. About the bin range and values, it was just to generate a toy example

Answer (score 2):

I think the main issue you have in your code is that your kernel has a thread strategy to have each thread process a row, and you have 2 rows in your `feature` dataset, but you are launching 12 threads total:

```
### Kernal Configuration
threads_per_block = 6
blocks = 2
```

10 of those threads will be indexing out-of-bounds.  For 2 rows you only need 2 threads.  We can fix this multiple ways, but I will add a "thread-check" to your kernel code, to prevent out-of-bounds threads from doing anything.

You are also histogramming values that don't fit in your output array.  Let's suppose your `feature` has a input value of 4 at some location.  Let's put that value through your arithmetic:

```
    bin_number = np.int32(nbins * (np.float32(4) - np.float32(-4)) / (np.float32(4) - np.float32(-4)))
```

That is 10 * (4-(-4))/(4-(-4))

So that is a bin index of 10.  But you only have 10 bins, so valid bin index can only go up to 9.  Which means some of your input values (e.g. 4, 5) will not be recorded in your output.

The following code is your code to add the threadcheck, plus the range of input adjusted.  And I am printing out the input, the bin each input value was assigned, and the output bins.  It seems to be working correctly.

```
$ cat t65.py
import numba
import numpy as np
from numba import cuda

np.random.seed(0)
feature = np.random.randint(1, high=4, size=(2,6), dtype=int)
output = np.zeros(20).astype(np.float32).reshape(2,10)
mybin = np.empty_like(feature)
### Kernal Configuration
threads_per_block = 6
blocks = 2

# moving data to device
d_feature = cuda.to_device(feature)
d_output = cuda.to_device(output)
feature_size = d_feature.shape[1]
d_mybin = cuda.to_device(mybin)

@cuda.jit
def row_wise_histogram(feature, output, mybin, n):
    xmin = np.float32(-4.0)
    xmax = np.float32(4.0)
    idx = cuda.grid(1)
    nbins = 10
    bin_width = (xmax - xmin) / nbins
    if  idx < output.shape[0]:
        for i in range(n):
            # Each thread will take all the row features to generate historgram
            input = feature[idx][i]
            bin_number = np.int32(nbins * (np.float32(input) - np.float32(xmin)) / (np.float32(xmax) - np.float32(xmin)))
            mybin[idx][i] = bin_number
            if bin_number >= 0 and bin_number < output.shape[1]:
                cuda.atomic.add(output[idx], bin_number, 1)


row_wise_histogram[blocks, threads_per_block](d_feature, d_output, d_mybin, feature_size)

print(feature)
print(d_mybin.copy_to_host())
print(d_output.copy_to_host())
$ python t65.py
[[1 2 1 2 2 3]
 [1 3 1 1 1 3]]
[[6 7 6 7 7 8]
 [6 8 6 6 6 8]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  3.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  4.  0.  2.  0.]]
$ cuda-memcheck python t65.py
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
[[1 2 1 2 2 3]
 [1 3 1 1 1 3]]
[[6 7 6 7 7 8]
 [6 8 6 6 6 8]]
[[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  2.  3.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  4.  0.  2.  0.]]
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that when I restrict the input values to 1..3, then the maximum bin index is 8 (do the math).  If I increase the input range to include 4, the maximum bin index goes to 10, which "won't fit".  You're correctly handling this case, but it may confuse you, as these values of 4 or 5 won't be recorded in the output.  Histogram bin arithmetic is fun.  You will need to work out exactly what you want.

Also note that if you run this code, you should see output almost exactly the same as above.  If you don't, there is a good chance your numba or cuda install is broken somehow, and the additional run I show with `cuda-memcheck` will help to discover what may be the issue.

Note that since you are using atomics anyway, there isn't any particular need to assign one thread to each row, you could instead assign one thread to each input point.  But that isn't your question; it's a story for another day.  Conversely, if you do proceed with one thread per row, each thread doing effectively a private histogram, there is no particular need to use atomics.

Comment: Many thanks Robert, it is exactly what I wanted. Much appreciated the expert advice on the pitfalls. One thing, as you said try to use cuda-memcheck  `========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= This tool is deprecated and will be removed in a future release of the CUDA toolkit
========= Please use the compute-sanitizer tool as a drop-in replacement
========= t65.py: Permission denied
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors`   so i tried  `compute-sanitizer python t65.py 
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors` and it work well

Comment: @RoberCrovella, there is one thing I would request you to clarify. I have reduced thread block size from 6  to 2 threads  which works the same. I am confused with the `output[idx]` part. The `idx` will usually be  0 or 1 then how it puts values in the `output` to its position ranging from 0-9 index ?

Comment: an atomic add in numba cuda has 3 arguments.  The first argument is the base pointer.  It is usually the name of a global array, but in this case it is the pointer to a row in a 2D array.  The second argument is the **offset** from that base pointer.  So by passing `bin_number` as the offset to the base pointer (i.e. the beginning of the row), you are effectively indexing *into the row* by the `bin_number`, this is where the position ranging from 0-9 index (into the row) comes from.  The 3rd argument of course is the amount to add to that location.

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation!